# Why is ndimage.maximum_filter not working a expected

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.ndimage

I have a problem where I need to detect the local maximum of an image. I used the ndimage.maximum_filter to detect local maximas.
Here is a sample code:

```
image = np.array([1,0,6,1,8,9,6,4])    

neigh = [1,0,1]

filtered_image = ndimage.maximum_filter(image, footprint=neigh, mode='constant', cval=np.inf)
print(f"filtered_image: {filtered_image}")
```

The code applies a 1D filter of size 3 on the image.
This code gives me the following result:

> filtered_image: [0 6 1 8 9 8 9 6]

The first element of the array is 0, and normally it should be np.inf.
I don't know why is that the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small bug, `int` images with `cval=inf` 
(`np.array` -> `int` or `float` or ..., depending on the types of the arg)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage 

image = np.array([1,0,6,1,8,9,6,4], dtype=float )
neigh = [1,0,1]
filtered_image = ndimage.maximum_filter( image, footprint=neigh,
    mode='constant', cval=np.inf )
print(f"filtered_image: {filtered_image}")  # [inf 6 1 8 9 8 9 inf]
```